# beginner in blender, having trouble with face filling

Tags: mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

g'day, i am creating a bowl in blender, however i have come across this problem that i can not solve. I have an extrusion on the bottom for a lip. The lip works fine, however because it's an extrusion the top faces arent filled in. However when i fill these faces i have this weird mesh morphing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CKRe8F8Sndrcnj7MBSMp5Gn-u1MBH517/view?usp=sharing just use the google drive link

Comment: I can't see the thing you show in picture 1, also it's better to put the Subdivision Surface below the Solidify

Comment: Apply the solidify modifier _before_ you model the foot rim. Then you will have separate geometry for top and bottom faces of your bowl and adding and extruding the foot on the bottom face will not affect the inside of the bowl and you won't have to fill a crease there.